# What's the best way to escape a bash command in python?

Tags: python, bash

I have a function that takes in a command as a string, and runs it on an AWS container using the `aws` binary.

The command adds a few extra symbols before and after the command the user requested to run - I won't get into why.

```py
def run_command_on_aws_container(command: str, aws_info):
    full_command = f"bash -c 'echo -n \"|\"; {command}; echo -n \"|\"'"

    subprocess.run(["aws", ..., "--command", full_command], ...)
    ...

command_to_run_on_aws_machine = 'python -c "for i in range(10): print(i)"'

run_command_on_aws_container(command_to_run_on_aws_machine, aws_info)
```

This works, but only if my `command_to_run_on_aws_machine` doesn't contain single-quotes. If my `command_to_run_on_aws_machine` was this for example:

```py
command_to_run_on_aws_machine = "python -c 'for i in range(10): print(i)'"
```

which is exactly the same command, but using single quotes instead of double quotes, the whole thing crashes. Or at least it doesn't do what you'd expect.

Is there a way to make my `run_command_on_aws_container` function work with both strings, so that as long as the `command` arg is a proper bash command, it will run? Ideally not just blindly converting all single quotes to double quotes in a string, but in a way where if the command includes properly escaped quotes, it will still work?

Note: All commands being sent to `run_command_on_aws_container` as the `command` arg are hard-coded into the program. There's no security issue here of executing arbitrary commands on a remote system. This is only for convenience, so that code being written outside of the function doesn't need to worry about how to properly use a string.

Comment: Use `shlex.quote()`

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you confirm if the presence of the `|` character implies shell piping or not?  Doesn't seem that way, but will all the special escapes it's hard to see at a glance.  Happy to learn about `shlex.quote` :-)

Comment: @JLPeyret in this case - no - no piping involved in this sample code. In my actual code, there is, making things even more fun :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`shlex.quote()` is designed specifically for this:

```python
full_command = "bash -c " + shlex.quote(f'echo -n "|"; {command}; echo -n "|"')
```

Comment: I came across `shlex.quote` a few minutes ago, before I created this post, and tried to use it in a few different ways, but wasn't successful. Your example made it work almost right away. Thanks!